# Find differences between local repo and remote repo in git

Tags: windows, linux, git

I'm currently working from two different computers on a project - a laptop running Linux, and a desktop running Win7. I'm using an ubuntu server with gitolite on it to host my repos.

I'm trying to write a quick script that will do two things :

1. Check if anything has changed on the local repo, since the last push.  If so, it should commit changes, push the commit to the remote repo

   1a.  I'm not sure how this works, but I DONT want this commit to overwrite changes in files that I haven't changed locally (ie: they may have been changed on the other computer, and pushed)
2. After that, it should check if the remote repo has any files that have been changed since my last pull (see 1a.). If so, pull those changes into the local repo.

The intention of this script is to keep both computers synced with each other, without having to manually do all of this git work each time. I would like to have this run periodically (once every half hour?), so I don't want it to take a huge amount of resources, if possible.

I don't need the whole script written for me (unless it is just a couple lines) - just point me towards the commands I will need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the output of:

```
git ls-remote <remote>
git show-ref
```

Although generally what is done is to fetch (not pull) the remote and compare the remote branches  with your local branches. If you have non-fast forward merges, you can't really automate because manual intervention on the merge will be required before pushing again.

Comment: So I can use git show-ref to check if my local repo matches the remote repo (for step 2).  Any ideas on step 1?  Also, is there a way to force my merge to override those non-fast forward things?  Like a git push -f?

Comment: If you do a git push -f you will likely lose (permanently) changes that were made by the other person that is pushing into the repo. And when that happens the other person will also be unable to pull the overwritten repo without major conflicts. I think you want to pull (or merge) using the `-s ours` option which will merge the tree to your original state but it won't screw up the repository for the other person (and their commits will still be there if you need to recover them).